# Wix Patch Generation issues

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I am currently struggling to build a working patch for our product using WiX 3.7.

We are currently at the development stage with our product and I want to validate the process for building patches before we RTM so that I know the original installer has any information required.

I have tried to follow the [Patch Creation Properties](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/patch_building.htm) approach detailed on the WiX toolset website, I built my two installers with identical UpgradeCode and ProductCode since this is a small update - the only difference was a single text file called something_to_patch.txt.

When I generated the patch it is correctly identifying that the data in something_to_patch.txt has changed; the log file from msimsp.exe contains:

```
INFO Comparing Files: D:\Development\xa3-modular\XAnalyser3\Installer\Patches\tmpinstall\target\Warwick Control Technologies\X-Analyser 3\something_to_patch.txt D:\Development\xa3-modular\XAnalyser3\Installer\Patches\tmpinstall\origin\Warwick Control Technologies\X-Analyser 3\something_to_patch.txt...
INFO Comparing bytes...
INFO Different content...
INFO File Key: something_to_patch.txt is modified
INFO: Phase IV: Entering Generate Payload.
INFO: Phase V:  Entering Generate MSP.
INFO:        Generating Patch Metadata.
```

When I then try to install the patch it seems to "install" successfully (it is shown in the Add and Remove Programs Updates section) and the log indicates that the was successful, however the installed file is not updated.

With a verbose log output from the patch there is an awful lot of information (I can upload it somewhere if necessary) but the part that stood out to me are the lines

```
MSI (s) (6C:60) [12:12:07:205]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=gsbnpcwh.txt|something_to_patch.txt,SourceCabKey=something_to_patch.txt,DestName=something_to_patch.txt,Attributes=4608,FileSize=21,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,,,InstallMode=58982400,HashOptions=0,HashPart1=-656054953,HashPart2=1104329007,HashPart3=-1666156207,HashPart4=-1000780969,,)
MSI (s) (6C:60) [12:12:07:205]: File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Warwick Control Technologies\X-Analyser 3\something_to_patch.txt;  Won't Overwrite;    Won't patch;    Existing file is unversioned and unmodified - hash matches source file
```

So it knows that it has something to write to that file but it seems to skip over it because the hashes match.

I have tested both the "target" MSI and the "origin" RTM MSI files and they install different text files as expected.

Does anyone have any recommendations or additional log files etc that would be useful to help trace the problem. I can add my wxs files if necessary but they're pretty much identical to the [sample](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/patch_building.htm) on the WiX website.

Regards,
Anthony

Comment: What's the value of REINSTALLMODE?